# PHP redirect to same url but different hostname

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I have the following use-case. My site is named www.example.nl. I want to use the same website code for my new domain www.example.eu. But I don't want to copy all, so I am investigating a forward/redirect mechanism. So, when a user enters www.example.eu/home.php it should redirect/forward to www.example.nl/home.php.

But: **I want the URL to stay www.example.eu/home.php**

I have a hosting provider and I am not able to access Apache files. I use PHP and Javascript as software stack. I looked on the Web but could not find a solution for this (except for the Apache configuration).

Comment: You can use dns to forward the url to the same ip as the .nl server

Comment: OK but note that I am not able to configure any tooling. Except for PHP/Javascript. So: no access to DNS settings and/or Apache

Comment: Ok, maybe you can create an .htaccess file with the following contents: `RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.nl/$1 [R=301,L]` This not exactly what you want but it will redirect the site to the .nl version

Answer (score 0):

Once you cannot access/modify any tool, as mentioned in the comments, there is the possibility to access the original website from an `iframe`.

Of course, it's not ideal, but may solve your problem, although you will see always the `home.php` in your address bar.

Also, depending the content and your server configuration, you could get an error, like `X-Frame Options: DENY` or `X-Frame Options: SAMEORIGIN` (more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)). This happens if you try websites like Google, Yahoo, Instagram etc. I've tried to a personal website I have and it worked fine.

If you want to try, here's a possible `home.php` file to host in your *www.example.eu*.

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px;" src="http://www.example.nl/home.php"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

If it works for all your redirections and you end up using it, then you will have only one file for your `.eu` version of the website.

As I said before, it's an option, but it's not ideal.
The best would be just redirect using a DNS or Apache.

Hope it somehow useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) commands ?
Create a home.php file under .eu domain and include the contents of the file from the .nl domain. This might look as a bit "quick'n'dirty" solution - but should work.

You could also think of creating symbolic links under .eu home directory - but the question is whether you can do it... If you cannot do it directly using provider's GUI - maybe create these links using script and [link()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.link.php) command.